# What is wrong with this CMAC computation?

Tags: cmac

I have an example of a CMAC computation, which I want to reproduce in Python, however I am failing. The example looks like this:

```
key = 3ED0920E5E6A0320D823D5987FEAFBB1
msg = CEE9A53E3E463EF1F459635736738962&cmac=
```

The expected (truncated) CMAC looks like this (note: truncated means that every second byte is dropped)

```
ECC1E7F6C6C73BF6
```

So I tried to reenact this example with the following code:

```
from Crypto.Hash import CMAC
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify

def generate_cmac(key, msg):
    """generate a truncated cmac message.
    Inputs: 
    key: 1-dimensional bytearray of arbitrary length
    msg: 1-dimensional bytearray of arbitrary length
    Outputs:
    CMAC: The cmac number
    CMAC_t: Trunacted CMAC"""


    # Generate CMAC via the CMAC algorithm
    cobj = CMAC.new(key=key, ciphermod=AES)
    cobj.update(msg)
    mac_raw = cobj.digest()

    # Truncate by initializing an empty array and assigning every second byte
    mac_truncated = bytearray(8 * b'\x00')
    it2 = 0
    for it in range(len(mac_raw)):
        if it % 2:
            mac_truncated[it2:it2+1] = mac_raw[it:it+1]
            it2 += 1
    return mac_raw, mac_truncated

key = unhexlify('3ED0920E5E6A0320D823D5987FEAFBB1') # The key as in the example
msg = 'CEE9A53E3E463EF1F459635736738962&cmac='      # The msg as in the example
msg_utf = msg.encode('utf-8')
msg_input = hexlify(msg_utf)                        # Trying to get the bytearray
mac, mact_calc = generate_cmac(key, msg_input)      # Calculate the CMAC and truncated CMAC
# However the calculated CMAC does not match the cmac of the example
```

My function `generate_cmac()` works perfectly for other cases, why not for this example?

(If anybody is curious, the example stems from [this document](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12196.pdf) Page 18/Table 6)

Edit: An example for a successful cmac computation is the following:

```
mact_expected = unhexlify('94EED9EE65337086')       # as stated in the application note
key = unhexlify('3FB5F6E3A807A03D5E3570ACE393776F') # called K_SesSDMFileReadMAC
msg = []                                            # zero length input
mac, mact_calc = generate_cmac(key, msg)            # mact_expected and mact_calc are the same
assert mact_expected == mact_calc, "Example 1 failed" # This assertion passes
```

Comment: BTW: if you refer people to 'this document', it might be somewhat helpful if you indicate what document you're talking about.  Lots of documents have a Page 18, and some of them might have a table 6 on that page...

Comment: Typically, when a CMAC implementation gets it right for some inputs and wrong for others, that's likely an indication that either you're not computing one of $k_1, k_2$ correctly, or sometimes using the wrong one (you're supposed to select it based on message length). On the other hand, you're using a canned CMAC implementation. Can you check if you get the correct result in the input is not a multiple of 16 in length, or the result is consistently correct for some keys but not others? If so, that would suggest that your canned implementation is not, in fact, correct.

Comment: This code is not ready for review (and we don't do these, see our [rules on topicallity](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Worst issues: the first parameter of `generate_cmac` is passed unhexlified thus presumably is a bytestring, while the second is hexlified, and even double-hexlified for the most of it, but there is not a single comment or solid landmark to tell what's supposed to be bytes, string, or hexlified bytes. On top of that the message being CMACed ends in `&cmac=`, which is even more odd than not plain truncating the CMAC, as customary.

Comment: @poncho: Thanks for pointing out, I forgot the hyperlink. I edited the question accordingly. Can you point me toward a working (python) implementation against which I can check my function?

Comment: @fgrieu: I apologize if I did not oblige to the rules here. How can I rephrase my question in order to be acceptable. Furthermore, I would like to point out that this is an example from the document I linked. Therefore the ```&cmac=``` is not my fault :D. Concerning your other remars: I edited in order to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: **overhexlification**

Much to my stupefaction, the [linked example](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12196.pdf#page=18) indeed seems to mean `CEE9A53E3E463EF1F459635736738962&cmac=`when it writes that, since the box below contains 76 hex characters for the the 38 bytes coding that in ASCII, that is `434545394135334533453436334546314634353936333537333637333839363226636d61633d`.

However I'm positive that this does not need to be further hexlified on the tune of 76 bytes as the code does. In other words, my bets are on

```
key = unhexlify('3ED0920E5E6A0320D823D5987FEAFBB1')
msg = 'CEE9A53E3E463EF1F459635736738962&cmac='.encode()
mac, mact_calc = generate_cmac(key, msg)
```

Comment: You are indeed right, I tried this and it works. Thanks for the assistance. Just one more note: NXP often has some confusing cryptographie going.